# Drop-in replacement for mb_substr?

Tags: php

I need to use `substr` on a multi-byte string without destroying it, but the PHP mb_ extension is not available. Is there a drop-in replacement for `mb_substr`?

Comment: What's wrong with `mb_substr`?

Comment: If you get `l'&e`, your text cannot be `l'é`.

Comment: Do you have a concrete reason for wanting to reinvent a wheel `mb_substr` has already solved (mixing metaphors)?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_substr() in /var/www/html/2011/anand/ajax.php on line 4

Comment: So you don't have the mb extension enabled? Then you're in a bit of a pinch. The best thing to do is to enable it. Is this really not possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can do the trick using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with an empty pattern if your string is unicode.

A simple implementation could be :

```
function my_mb_substr($string, $offset, $length)
{
  $arr = preg_split("//u", $string);
  $slice = array_slice($arr, $offset + 1, $length);
  return implode("", $slice);
}

echo my_mb_substr("重庆大学", 1, 2); // 庆大
```

Comment: +1 I'd even use this to replace `mb_substr` like `if (!function_exists('mb_substr'))  { function mb_substr ... }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Patchwork UTF-8](https://github.com/nicolas-grekas/Patchwork-UTF8), a library that provides many Unicode functions and fallbacks for the `mb_` functions, should they not be available. It's a drop-in replacement, just `include` it and use `mb_substr` as usual. It does require PHP 5.3 though.

Comment: nice, didn't knew that lib :-) a cleaner answer

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess is that you have HTML entities, so your text is actually something like this:

```
EDF, leader mondial de l'&eacute;nergie nucl&eacute;aire
```

... which, rendered through a web browser, is displayed as:

```
EDF, leader mondial de l'énergie nucléaire
```

This is unrelated to multi-byte issues. The root problem is that HTML is a rich text format and cannot be manipulated carelessly as plain text can.

You'll need to get a plain text representation of your data you can work on. You can strip HTML tags with [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags), but it needs to be done *before* truncating. After that, you can convert HTML entities with the [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) function:

```
$text = "EDF, leader mondial de l'&eacute;nergie nucl&eacute;aire";
$output = html_entity_decode($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
```

... assuming that your site uses UTF-8.

Note: the MB extension offers a similar feature:

```
$text = "EDF, leader mondial de l'&eacute;nergie nucl&eacute;aire";
$output = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

Comment: "IMHO less reliable"? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @deceze - Sure, I was too vague.

Comment: Thanks. Can you name an entity that `mb_...` supports that `html_...` doesn't? I've just never come across this issue before, so I'll take the opportunity to ask you about it. :)

Comment: I've lost my notes on the subject. I'd better edit the answer and omit such reference, so I won't confuse anyone.